# XAMPP .htaccess in subdirectory not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have XAMPP set up and configured. My project is called 'gpstudios' and I have a virtual server called "local.gpstudios" (also declared in hosts). This allows me to use "local.gpstudios/" which allows for the correct root directory access.
In htdocs I have a functioning .htaccess. It is in use for several other projects.
In htdocs/gpstudios I want to have another .htaccess for itself.

I've tried altering the httpd.conf and restarting Apache:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/gpstudios">
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't change anything. The .htaccess in htdocs/gpstudios has yet to work a single time, no matter what I write in it.
It currently just contains the line "deny from all" which should get an error in the browser.

How do I get it to work while not deleting/moving my other .htaccess?

[EDIT]

I've tried everything. My virtualhost settings look perfect. Everywhwere says AllowOverride All and Allow from all. Completely stumped.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't believe it. I barely can myself.
I sorted it out. I worked it all by myself.
After a quick google it would appear nobody ever on the internet has encountered the same problem I had.

It turns out the .htaccess file was formatted with CR linebreaks instead of LF or CRLF.
I was using PHPStorm to edit the htaccess file, and PHPStorm prefers CR.
The closest I ever had to it working was triggering 500 errors when I'd fill it with a few statements.

Apache.... What are you playing at? Why are you like that? Goddamnit.
It's past midnight now, and I've spent all day working on this.
I'm exhausted. I feel completely defeated. Just a husk of the man I was this morning.
Now my ordeal is finally over I'm off to bed, not before I spend a few delicate moments with myself screaming into a pillow.
Good night.

Comment: OMG, thx for this... Working on both Mac and Windows machines i couldnt get my head around this either.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this into your `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost local.gpstudios:80
<VirtualHost local.gpstudios:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@local.gpstudios
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/gpstudios"
    ServerName local.gpstudios
    ServerAlias www.local.gpstudios

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/gpstudios">
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it made a difference, but it still isn't working. You see, I already had that in my vhosts file, except the the lines NameVirtualHost local.gpstudios:80 and <VirtualHost local.gpstudios:80> were NameVirtualHost *:80 and 
<VirtualHost *:80>. Now it appears that local.gpstudios inherits the root .htaccess, but still ignores its own.

Comment: `.htaccess` file your taking about is in **gpstudios** or in a sub-directory?

Comment: It's in gpstudios. Honestly, I'm not doing anything daft, I've checked and triple checked and tried everything that's been suggested through google results. I've been  trying to get this working all day... Just maddening.

Comment: I should also mention my version of XAMPP is using Apache 2.4.3

Comment: Two thing: 1- put the content of your `.htacccess` here. 2- in your `httpd-default.conf`, check if there is `AccessFileName .htaccess`.